# Whatsapp isn't performing the expected daily backup

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a Galaxy S10e with Whatsapp backup setup to backup **daily** to google drive, according to the guidelines on [Samsung's website](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-to-back-up-or-restore-whatsapp-data/):

[image]

However the backup isn't taking place automatically.  It only backs up if I manually initiate it.  What could be the reason that Whatsapp isn't doing it?

Comment: Four points: 1. Change backup frequency to "daily". 2. Change "Wi-Fi only" to "Wi-Fi and Cellular" under Back up over. 3. Select a backup account. 4. Disable battery optimizations for WhatsApp. Do these solve the problem?

Comment: how do I disable battery optimizations?

Comment: That actually differs from device to device, but if you have the Smart Manager app provided by Samsung, you should have that option there (under Battery option). Otherwise, do a search in Settings.